# how to add controls to a textarea in Html page?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I want to add controls above my `textarea` in Html page like the one you see while asking a question on this site.

I want to know if this is possible with `html5` or will I need to use `JavaScript`?

Is there a specific option/tag or do I have to create custom class/function?

[image: screenshot of about me section on StackOverflow]

Comment: You just have to create a simple row of buttons.

Comment: You need javascript, and could start by looking at https://www.tinymce.com/ and http://ckeditor.com/ which I think are considered the de facto choices in this area. As suggested above, writing this yourself would be "reinventing the wheel" for sure.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look for a 3rd party rich text editor.  I've written one of these from scratch and they're a royal pain in the derriere.  I'd only recommend doing this yourself if you know the subject matter and your question wording tells me you don't.

Comment: Yeah I'm a novice, I'm doing a project for my class so I wanted to include a textarea with controls. I'll look into 3rd party text editors if I can include them in my page and access it offline.

Comment: @Akshay_R If you need a simple `textarea` without much formatting options then you can create buttons that will make the text area editable on click using the `contenteditable` property of a div. Otherwise you can use `tinymce` or `ckeditor` or some other third party editors.